# If -match is case-insensitive, why do we need -imatch?

Tags: powershell

It seems redundant to provide `-match` and `-imatch` if `-match` is already case-insensitive. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for stackoverflow. To answer your question you can use it to be explicit. It shows clearly the authors intention to be case insensitive.

Comment: This is a question you should pose to the MS Powershell team via the MS Powershell issues GitHub. There's nothing a public Q&A site like SO, can do about the native features of PowerShell. With cross-platform PowerShell (OSX/Linux) files and the like is case sensitive. We all know Windows is not, but if you get files or data in a file you are trying to evaluate that you cannot change in the file, then that is why those exist. What is or is not useful any any solution offering is up to you and your use case.

Comment: How is this question not appropriate? I'm asking a question about code and if there's a detail I'm unaware of. I'm not expecting an answer from the PS team or anyone to _do_ anything about it, just an explanation of the subtlety here, as @mklement0 does so nicely in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate on [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer)'s comment:

**The `i`-prefixed variants of [PowerShell operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators) that (also) operate on *strings* are never *necessary***. In fact, they are simply *aliases* of their non-prefixed forms, so that **`-imatch` is the same as `-match`**, for instance, and - with string input - always acts case-*insensitively*, as PowerShell generally does.

**These variants exist for *symmetry* with the `c`-prefixed operator variants**, which explicitly request case-*sensitive* operation (with string input).

In other words: **you can use the `i`-prefixed variants to make it *explicit* that a given operation is case-*insensitive*.**

However, **to someone familiar with PowerShell's *fundamentally* case-insensitive nature, that isn't necessary** - and that's probably why you rarely see the `i`-prefixed variants in practice.